# Add newcommands to a package with arguments

Tags: macros, package-writing

I want to make a package that has a bunch of commands that I define in all of my Problem Sets. I'm running into an issue where the compiler does not recognize commands that I define that have an argument. Here is a brain-dead simple example of something that isn't compiling and I can't seem to find out why.

This is my style file, aptly named `mystyle.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}

\newcommand{\test}{\Huge}
\newcommand{\hding}[1]{#1\newline\normaltext}
```

`mystyle.sty` has two commands in it. \test just makes the text Huge, and `\hding` appends a newline and changes the font back to normal. My brain-dead simple `.tex` file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
Hello World!
%\hding{Hello World!} Hello World!
\test Hello World!
\end{document}
```

With just the test function, everything works fine. But if I try to compile with the `\hding` function uncommented, the compiler yells at me with the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hding #1->#1\newline \normaltext 

l.7 \hding{Hello World!}
                     Hello World!
```

What is going on? What am I not understanding?

Comment: There is no command called `\normaltext`. Perhaps you're thinking of `\textnormal`. And by the way, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarise yourself further with our format.

Comment: Wow, I knew it was something dumb. But nothing was complaining about \normaltext. TexStudio was fine with it, and the compiler didn't say a thing. Ah well, the more you know. Thanks for the welcoming btw.

Comment: The error message shows the command definition (`\hding #1->#1\newline \normaltext`) which means that the undefined control sequence is one of the commands used within the definition of `\hding` rather than `\hding` itself.

Comment: Ok, I shall remember that for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probable, the `\normaltext` command should rather read `\normalsize`, as the OP first changes the font size to `\Huge` and `\hding` should restore it to the normal font, this could be understood as restoring the original fontsize, which can be achieved by `\normalsize`.

As far as I know, there is no `\normaltext` command.

`\textnormal`, as suggested by ChrisS is rather used in math mode, in order to get normal text, not in math font.

## mystyle.sty

```
    \ProvidesPackage{mystyle}

    \newcommand{\test}{\Huge}
    \newcommand{\hding}[1]{#1\newline\normalsize}%
```

## main file

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{mystyle}


\begin{document}
\[\textnormal{Hello World!}\]
\[Hello World\]
Hello World!
\hding{Hello World!} Hello World!
Before \test Afterwards: Hello World!
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note**

In principle, an environment would be better to achieve the font switch and restoring afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I picked up that command from some website, and none of the tools I was using told me it was invalid. the error messages were very misleading and I ended up spending way too much time on this rather than actually working on the assignment DX. Thanks again.